# Firebase function works locally but not when deployed

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When using postman to access the router via localhost I get the expected response of "Hello name" but when trying to access it deployed I'm getting this:
[response body shows google signin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPpxr.png)

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.Hello = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
res.send("Hello " + req.query.firstName);
})
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to actually be a postman issue.

Still not sure exactly what was wrong, but the url worked as expected in the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying the HTTP fuction with default values, the function [always will require authentication](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating).

If you don't want to authenticate when calling the function, you can follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/console#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation).

Also when creating the function, you can mark the option "Allow Unautheticated" in the Cloud Console or adding the flag `--allow-unauthenticated` when using `gcloud functions deploy`.